# Amortization program with java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I need to calculate the amount of interest that a person pays yearly on a loan, and to show the declining balance of the loan on an annual basis. I understand how to get the numbers on paper but I can't figure out how to make the code for it and other forums haven't helped at all.

An example is of what it should look like is:

```
Enter loan amount: 90000
Enter loan duration in years: 15
Enter interest rate as a percent: 6.75


For a 15 year loan of $90000.00 at 6.75% interest

Monthly payment =   $   796.42
Total interest =    $   53355.33

Yearly Balances
Year    Interest    Loan Balance
 1      5965.23     86408.21   
 2      5715.14     82566.33    
 3      5447.64     78456.94    
 4      5161.51     74061.43    
 5      4855.46     69359.87    
 6      4528.10     64330.94    
 7      4177.95     58951.87    
 8      3803.41     53198.26    
 9      3402.80     47044.03    
 10     2974.29     40461.31    
 11     2515.95     33420.24    
 12     2025.70     25888.91    
 13     1501.31     17833.19    
 14     940.40      9216.58    
 15     340.45      -0.00
```

> What I currently have:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Loan
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int loanAmount, loanDurationYears, month;
    double interestRate, monthlyPayment, totalInterest;

    System.out.print("Enter loan amount:");
    loanAmount = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter loan duration in years:");
    loanDurationYears = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter interest rate as a percent:");
    interestRate = keyboard.nextDouble();
    keyboard.close();

    System.out.println("Loan amount: $" + loanAmount);
    System.out.println("Loan duration: " + loanDurationYears + " years");
    System.out.println("Interest rate: " + interestRate + "%");

    monthlyPayment = payment(loanAmount, loanDurationYears, interestRate);
    totalInterest = ((monthlyPayment * (loanDurationYears*12))-loanAmount);
    printTotals(loanAmount, loanDurationYears, interestRate, monthlyPayment, totalInterest);
  }
  public static double payment(int loanAmount, int loanDurationYears, double interestRate)
  {
      int a = loanAmount;
      int n = (loanDurationYears*12);
      double i = ((interestRate*.01)/12);
      double monthlyPayment = a*(Math.pow((1+i),n)*i)/((Math.pow((1+i),n))-1);
      return monthlyPayment;
  }
  public static void printTotals(int loanAmount, int loanDurationYears, double interestRate, double monthlyPayment, double totalInterest)
  {
      System.out.println("For a " + loanDurationYears + " year loan of $" + loanAmount + " at " + interestRate + "% interest:");
      System.out.printf("Monthly payment = $"+ "%.2f", monthlyPayment);
      System.out.println();
      System.out.printf("Total interest = $"+ "%.2f", totalInterest);
      System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Comment: do not use doubles or floats at all when handling currency, doubles and floats do not store decimals with perfect precision

Comment: @gia I've read that on another forum but my professor specifically told us to use doubles for some reason.

Comment: he probably wanted you to fail and learn by experience

Comment: So how exactly would I make the amortization? I'm thinking I need a for loop and then I know how to get the first month's numbers but I can't figure out how to go past that.

Comment: for loop, keep the loan balance at 100%, calculate first month interest and payment, deduct, now you have your new loan balance print everything, next loop on the for, repeat, keep looping while loanbalance > 0

Answer (score 0):

floats and doubles shouldn't be used for currency because the decimal part will not be precise all the time.

However, since you must use doubles I suggest you move the decimal point a bit to the right  until you got all the precision you need.

eg. 100.26 will not be stored at anytime on a double, but 100260.00 will. This way, you don't lose precision on the important decimal digits ".26" and add a precise extra digit "0" at the end for precise rounding (if you need, otherwise stop at "26").

Because 100.26 must never be stored on a double (or you'll risk losing the decimal precision), you will read the user input as a string, or BigDecimal type and "multiply" by 1000 before passing the number to double. If you use a string you will find the dot, remove it, and place it 2/3 spots to the right before converting to double.

Because you will be multiplying by 1000, your double max value will be more limited, but if you don't plan to use huge numbers it may not be an issue.

You will do all your operations with x*1000 as normal and before printing you'll pass the double to one of your precise data types, format to remove the *1000 and print.

For this style you don't need a double specifically, can use long for instance, but there you go, you'll get the exact value with doubles.

Comment: Sorry if I'm a bother, but I'm still not understanding how to do it. I'm a little slow today.

Comment: I originally thought your issue was not getting the correct decimal values, my answer tackles that problem, but you claimed up there you actually  don't know how to do the loop. That's too basic sorry, you know how to do the calculation manually, so just write it in code. Research for loops, up there i told you broadly how the for loop would go.

Comment: Sorry, I'm now getting the loops to work, I just need to change it so that it displays the numbers for each year instead of each month.

Comment: on each step of the loop you can calculate an entire year as opposed to a single month, otherwise you can calculate monthly, but instead of printing, create an array and fill it up with your solutions, then have a second loop where you add them up by dozens to print yearly values, alternatively, have a counter k that adds up to 12, and two variables for adding up the monthly results, increment these after you calculate the monthly value, and whenever k hits 12, print them and reset to zero. print a final time once you leave the loop.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but not how to do it, but I'll search for it and figure it out. (My professor completely skipped arrays) 
Thanks for the help

Comment: use the final suggestion then, just keep a few variables, a counter and some adders.